# How to make a tab menu website (one page with inside other pages)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, menu, tabs

I would like to make a website with one page that has inside other pages.

To go from one page to another there's a tab or similar menu, so the page doesn't change, only the inner content.
The inner content has a lot of jquery and php: one has a form to make a search on the left and the results are shown in the center with datatables, so you can search inside the results, order them, etc, etc. When you switch from one content to another I don't want the content to be reset ( example: you make a search and then you go to another page/inner content  , when you come back the results of the search have to be still there). One of the tabs has a list( a submenu). When you select something from that list every page has to know and to use that selected value.

I thought the I can make all this with a lot of ajax, jquery ui tabs and php.

My questions are: it's good to make something like that? Is there another way to achieve what I want? Would it be better to make a normal menu with a lot of pages( no more inner content, but diffrent pages) and keep the selected value in session?In this case how can I keep the results?(session again?)

I hope that this question is allowed. Thank you all!

EDIT: I'm not asking the code( I know how jquery tabs and I searched google). I'm asking if it's a good practice to make something like that( one page with a lot of content) or it's better to use more pages?

**EDIT 2**: I'll refrase my question. I have to make something like this: 10 pages with different content that have php, jquery inside with a menu to navigate from one page to another. When you go from one page to another the searches and options selected in the pages that you left have to be still there, so that when you go back you can see them. One menu has a submenu with a list. When you select something from that list the selected value changes things in half of the pages(what you see inside). How should I do this?(don't show me code, tell me only what should I use to accomplish this)

**EDIT3**: I looked online and yahoo mail has what I want. The top of the page is allways the same. Then you have a menu: inbox, contacts, calendar. When you click on contacts only part of the page changes ( my inner content as I called it) and the same happens when you click on the other voices in the menu. Inside contacts, if you click on one contact you can see details about that contact, then if you click on inbox and again contacts you can still see the contact that you selected before. How can I achieve this?

Comment: and where is you code ??? please post your related codes too

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, can you post it?

Comment: Please, paragraphs, code...

Comment: I'll update with code, even if I don't know what code should I show you. I have some of the pages allready( the search one and others), but the pages are used by admin users and have sensible data in it, so I have to change a lot to show you the code.

Comment: its good to have such functionality as long its the one that `suits` your application. Plenty of such `HTML/Javascript` on internet, just google `tabbed content`.

Comment: @elclanrs - the yahoo mail example is ok? it's very difficult to show you decent code( I have to change it a lot). paragraphs ok?

Comment: The browser has tab support already. If i need to switch between tabs, the browser do it better. Why to emulate something that's stronger and already existing?

Comment: Because it has to be only one page and if you read my EDIT 2 you'll see that there are things that cannot be done if I use browser tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple achieve this by using jquery Tab [plugin](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)  .

or you should create your website template in which you replace content through ajax call.

```
       <html>
         ....

        <body>
            <div class="tab_container">
                <ul>
                       <li> Tab 1</li>
                       <li> Tab 2</li>
                </ul>
                <!-- integrate nested menu here -->
            </div>

            <div id="content">
              onclick on tab selection display appropriate content here
             </div>
        </body>

       </html>
```

I would suggest you if simply display content on the basis of tab selection than go for Ui-tabs

If you are developing complex website. and you need multiple menu. than try jquery dropdown menu. For displaying content, overwrite content div on the basis of tab  selection using ajax as I have mention in my example.

Here is link for jquery drop-down menu

http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-css3-dropdown-menu-plugin/996815?ref=jared501

[Live Example](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-css3-dropdown-menu-plugin/full_screen_preview/996815)

Comment: Thank you. I know jquery ui tabs, but I don't know if it's good pratice to use it for a complex website ( a part of it)

Comment: It sounds like you want to use tabs but making the page requests via AJAX?

Comment: tabs to display content ( but I don't want to use tabs..I'm searching for a solution and tabs I thought could be one).I have to use ajax because I don't want the page to "refresh" after a user searches something inside the db. Is there another way?

Comment: I have given him both option . But if complex structure as he mentioned in his question then I have suggested don't use tab here instead of tab go for drop-down menu or simpler menu. and on the basis of menu selection overwrite content

Comment: thank you for the drop-down menu...very nice! and to keep the content unchanged when I switch from one page to another?

Comment: @re_ru: Why content unchanged ? as I have earlier mention in my comment. you need to change content on the basis of your selection through ajax response . :)

Comment: Example: one page has a table with a lot of things, another page has a form that can be used to search something inside the db. I make a search and see the results and then I go to the other page. When I go again to the search page the user has to see his last search with the results ( that's what I mean when I say that the content doesn't have to change)

Comment: Oh Cool. Yes you can handle this ;)

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted, but I'll accept your answer because I'll use some parts of your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is for structure and some simple data explanation. 
If you want to make some data you should use something like PHP, ASP...

If you want to have some nice pages with effects use JavaScript and common this languages.
But you don't have exact question so the answer is the common

Comment: I'm using PHP, jquery. I'm sorry for not making my question clear. Thank you.

Comment: As I know there are some problems when you use jquery tabs. for example JS is off on the user's browser , history.. for me better use html menu and AJAX request so it will work with JS on/off on user's computer

Comment: Js off it's not a problem. It's only for some admin users and they know that they have to have js on. History? Why should that be a problem? I'll think about using html menu and ajax.